# Julia VegaLite.jl - How to disable the warninigs?

Tags: julia, warnings, visualization, vega-lite

When using the VegaLite.jl library for Julia, it is common to get several warnings when the visualization is not fully specified. For example, if I run the following code:

```
using VegaLite
α  = rand(10,2)
β  = rand(10,2)
v1 = @vlplot(:circle,x=α[:,1],y=α[:,2])
v2 = @vlplot(mark={"type"=:circle,color="red"},x=β[:,1],y=β[:,2])
@vlplot()+v1+v2
```

This will plot things correctly, but I get several warnings saying "QARN Missing type for channel "x", using "quantitative" instead".

Is there a way to disable this warnings? I mean, is there a way to suppress them? Note that I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl) to suppress all warnings.

Your code would like like this:

```
using Suppressor
@suppress begin
    v1 = @vlplot(:circle,x=α[:,1],y=α[:,2])
    v2 = @vlplot(mark={"type"=:circle,color="red"},x=β[:,1],y=β[:,2])
    @vlplot()+v1+v2
end
```

See other usage examples here: https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl#usage

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working, the messages are still showing.

Comment: Can you update your original question with the full code you are using or a MWE so I can try and mess around with it? You probably need to add the “using VegaLite” inside the @suppress block.

Comment: There you go. Updated the code. There is not much other than what was already written, just defining the variables.

Comment: Which Julia version are you using? I am on 1.5.1 and am not getting any warnings.

Comment: That’s strange. I’m using the same version. Are you using Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Something is amiss here, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/queryverse/VegaLite.jl/issues/341 and added info to an existing issue here: https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl/issues/31